# Test flight push notifications work. Does that mean my push notifications will work on the app store?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I've never made an app with push notifications before until now. Currently Im doing some testing with internal users on iTunesConnect and the push notifications are coming in fine.

Because of I’ve never done this before, I wanted to ask if this means my push notifications will still work when I actually release to the store? If not, could someone explain the difference between testflight and appstore builds are?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the push notification will work on `AppStore` too, as there are two types of push notification certificates:

1. Development (Used for testing development builds)
2. Production (Used for production builds such as Adhoc and AppStore)

So if the push is working fine in `TestFlight` it will defiantly work on `AppStore` builds.